# execve() is not executing the script when trying to run a script using it

Tags: c++, shell, operating-system

I wanna run a script using execve(). in the following code, I am printing environment variables in c++ code then I pass the output of those to a script called "usrscript" to print them there but the execve() is not executing the script. `

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
    int main(int argc, char *argv[], char * envp[]){ 
    char arg1[100]={};
    char arg2[100]={'\0'};
    char arg3[100]={};
    for (int i=0 ; envp[i] != NULL; i++){
        if('U'==envp[i][0] && 'S'==envp[i][1] && 'E'==envp[i][2] && 'R'==envp[i][3] && '='==envp[i][4]){ 
            for(int j=5 ;envp[i][j] != '\0';j++ ){
                arg1[j-5] =  envp[i][j];
            }
            cout<<arg1<<endl;
        }
        if('P'==envp[i][0] && 'A'==envp[i][1] && 'T'==envp[i][2] && 'H'==envp[i][3]){ 
            for(int j=5 ;envp[i][j] != '\0';j++ ){
                arg2[j-5] =  envp[i][j];
            }
            cout<<arg2<<endl;
        }
        if('T'==envp[i][0] && 'E'==envp[i][1] && 'R'==envp[i][2] && 'M'==envp[i][3]){ 
            for(int j=5 ;envp[i][j] != '\0';j++ ){
                arg3[j-5] = envp[i][j];
            }
            cout<<arg3<<endl;
        }
    }
    char cmd[]="./usrscript.sh";
    char scr[] ="usrscript";
    char os[]="OS2022=5ma32zw";
    
    char *const vectorArg[] = {scr,arg1,arg2,arg3,NULL};
    char *const vectorEnv[]= {os,NULL};


    execve(cmd,vectorArg,vectorEnv);
    cout<<"Failed\n";

    return 0;}
```

the script im passing to is :

```
#!usr/bin/bash
echo "hello"

for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done    

echo $OS2022
echo $TERM
echo $PATH
echo $USER
```

I have tried to look if I am passing incorrect values to execve(), but I could not find anything. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: _"... but the execve() is not working"_ means what exactly? Compiler error, runtime error, unexpected output?

Comment: Maybe `./usrscript.sh` is in the wrong folder. Likely the correct folder is the one containing the executable.

Comment: the usrscript.sh is in the same folder i have checked that. And by not wokring i mean that the failed statement at he end is printing and the script is not showing its output.

Comment: Also if you think the problem is with `vectorArg` why don't you test with fixed values at first instead of your for loop.

Comment: `for(int j=5 ;envp[i][j] != '\0';j++ ){ arg1[j-5] =  envp[i][j]; }` -> `strcpy( arg1, &envp[i][j] );`

Comment: the for loop is just for printing the envirment variables $user $path and $term. the usrscript works on its own

Comment: @hertz please note, that you're required to post a [mcve] with all, but ***minimal*** relevant information here. [Edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Check `errno` after the failure. Is the working directory the same directory as the executable is in?

Comment: im sorry im posting here for the first time

Comment: yes the working is the same as the executable directory. the errno is 8

Comment: there wasnt a ! in #usr/bin/bash now the errno is 2

Comment: I have eddited the code so that it is runnable.

Comment: @hertz *the for loop is just for printing the envirment variables $user $path and $term. the usrscript works on its own*  No it's not just printing the environment variables.  Those arguments are later passed to `execve()` as elements in `vectorArg[]`.

Comment: i tried using execve() with just strings in vectorArg[] instead of arguments it still does not work

Comment: Use `perror()` to print the errno in a readable form.

Comment: Is the script executable? Can you run it directly from a shell?

Comment: Yes, the script is executable separately. I solved it by replacing `#!usr/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash` , I don't know the reason why this worked tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by replacing `#!usr/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash` in the script.